# Node.js app cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**error:**
server running in development mode on port 5000
errorMongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

**db.js**

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected :${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`error${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
export default connectDB;
```

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import connectDB from './config/db.js'
import products from './data/products.js'


dotenv.config();

connectDB()

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("api is running... ");
});

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
  res.json(products);
});

app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
  const product = products.find(p => p._id === req.params.id);
  res.json(product);
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: What mongodb version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No More Deprecation Warning Options

**Mongoose** [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and
> useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always
> behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex
> are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options
> from your code.

db.js

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      // useUnifiedTopology: true, <-- no longer necessary
      // useNewUrlParser: true, <-- no longer necessary
      // useCreateIndex: true, <-- no longer necessary
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected :${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`error${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
export default connectDB;
```