# How can I connect MongoDB with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect MongoDB with my **signup.js**, but it's not connecting. I am unable to find the problem. How can I solve this?

**Code of signup.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require("./db/mydb");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port 4000`)
})
```

**Code of mydb.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydata",{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("connection successful")
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log("Not connected")
})
```

**Error:**

```
App listening on port 4000
Not connected
```

If the last log statement is replaced with `console.log(e)`, the output is:

```
MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366187/node-js-app-cannot-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-cluster/70366357#70366357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a simple example of how to connect [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) to Node.js using [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) and [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) on `localhost` obviously:

#### File *server.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Express and Mongoose connection!");
});

// Connect to db
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
  .then(() => {
    // Listen for requests
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(
        `Connected to DB & Server is listening at http://127.0.0.1:${port}`
      );
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And as we can read [in the Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options) → no more deprecation warning options

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and
> useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always
> behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex
> are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options
> from your code.

It was tested with: "express": "^4.18.1", "mongoose": "^6.6.5"